# Custom buttons doesn't display android studio

Tags: android

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">
android:orientation="vertical"
>
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="ImageButton Selected"/>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/button"/>
```

This is in my activity_main.xml

and this

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/round" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/round2" android:state_focused="true"/>
```

in my button.xml

the custom buttons are made with image button function
when I start the application It doesn't give error and shows only "imagebutton selected"
The problem can be with my image?being too large?

here are the images and they are png btw with 1000x1000..I know is big but being png I thought will be everything fine..now I have to find how to make the white background dissapear.
[here are the images round and round2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EPww.png)

I don't know what is a selector,I know that I've put them in the folder drawable and then I followed a tutorial to make custom buttons.
the images are vectors

here is how the emulator looks like [emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUGym.png)

Comment: Can you include your `@drawable/round`? It may be because you're using `layout_width="wrap_content"`, and it's just too small. Also, are your `item`s in a `selector`?

Comment: I edited I hope it helps you the additional info

Answer (score 0):

Your `button.xml` should look like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/round2" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <!-- focused -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/round3" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <!-- default -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/round"/>

</selector>
```

Also, you should reduce the size of your PNGs, that would take up a lot of space, and a lot of memory.

Comment: lol that thing at the end tricked me so bad..I did that and now the button came but it doesn't work and isn't placed good from this O turned into 0

Comment: is just 1 button and when I click it should change to the second one and it doesn't do that

Comment: Sorry, I left the default as `round` and the focused is `round2`. You would need a 3rd image if you want to support all 3 states ( default, pressed, and focused ). Maybe just use `round2` as your pressed state.

Comment: Probably yes but look I have 2 images right?I try to click and doesnt change neither the focused neither the pressed.I'll put a photo to see that isn't looking ok for some reason

Comment: I updated my answer to use different drawables for the states.

Comment: Thank you I understand.Can you please help find out why is looking like this the button?should I try with another image?

Comment: @AlexJ It may be getting squished. You could remove all the white space around it within the image. Just the actual button should be in the image.

Comment: It is just the button the white is from windows or whatever,they will not show that gride as in photoshop but trust me there is no white spot in the image is a vector.

Comment: It could be your layout, I'm not sure. Maybe try giving the button a fixed width/height.